# How to peek the deadletter messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter

It is very hard to find some good documentation on getting all the messages in a deadletter queue and getting to take a peek at them.

I have an Azure Servicebus Queue and everything I can find is for Azure Servicebus Topics.

Can someone help me with a quick guide?

Answer (score 4):

Dead letter queue is a secondary sub-queue where the poison messages are moved to.

In case of Azure Servicebus Queue the standard path for DLQ is `queuePath/$DeadLetterQueue`.
So you need to have another `queueClient` to read the DLQ.

And you will do something like this in .NET clients.

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "QueueName");

// do whatever regular queue reading activities

// this is for dead letter queue
var deadLetterClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(client.Path), ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

BrokeredMessage receivedDeadLetterMessage;
while ((receivedDeadLetterMessage = deadLetterClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(receivedDeadLetterMessage);
}
```

Comment: But I really have no clue what the topicPath is? Since this is a queue and not a topic?

Comment: sorry. I have updated the code with queue client. for some reason i thought you asked for topic and subs.

Comment: Hmm this give me the following error when it comes to the while loop:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll

Additional information: 40103: Invalid authorization token signature, 

Thanks though!

Comment: that sounds like an error with the SAS token.. debug and check the key that you use to connect. if you think the answer helped then do mark it as answer.

Comment: If you just target the DLQ, you can skip the main queue client creation and target its DLQ providing "queuePath/$DeadLetterQueue" as a path.

Comment: This answer has ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete.  The original question has "Peek at them".  I'm just pointing this out for future readers....not hatin' or anything.

Answer (score 4):

The Azure portal now offers a ***[service bus explorer (preview)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/sesrvice-bus-explorer/)*** tool to perform basic operations (such as Send, Receive, Peek) on Queues/Topics and their dead-letter subentities, right from the portal itself. Check this link on detailed instructions about using this tool -
[azure-service-bus-messaging-explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/explorer).
[image: service-bus-explorer-Azure-portal]

For using more advanced features such as import/export functionality or the ability to test topic, queues, subscriptions, relay services, notification hubs and events hubs, try using the community-owned operations support system (OSS) tool [service bus explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer).
[image: service-bus-explorer]
As on today, you can only peek 32 messages on the preview version of ***service bus explorer*** on Azure portal. So, if you have more messages to deal with, then you might want to opt for the above said standalone community-owned OSS tool.

Answer (score 4):

Updated code to peek messages from the dead letter queue using the new `ServiceBusClient` from `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>> GetDeadLetterMessagesAsync(string connectionString,
    string queueName, int maxMessages)
{
    var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    var receiverOptions = new ServiceBusReceiverOptions { SubQueue = SubQueue.DeadLetter };
    var receiver = serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName, receiverOptions);

    return await receiver.PeekMessagesAsync(maxMessages);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            //create queue Client
            var client = new Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusClient(your_connection_string);


            ServiceBusReceiver dlqReceiver = client.CreateReceiver(your_queue_name, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
            {
                SubQueue = SubQueue.DeadLetter
            });
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage dlqMessage = await dlqReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();

            var body = dlqMessage.Body;
            var msgtext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            //if you want to complete your message after reprocessing it
            await dlqReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(dlqMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];    
string queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queueName"];    
ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);    
MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString());    
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);    
string deadLetterQueuePath = QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(queueName);    
QueueClient deadletterQueueClient = factory.CreateQueueClient(deadLetterQueuePath);    
while (true)    
{    
       BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = deadletterQueueClient.Receive();    
       // Your Logic    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can get a list of all messages in the dead letter queue using Peek:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>> GetDeadLetterMessagesAsync(string connectionString,
    string queueName)
{
    var queue = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(queueName));
    var messageList = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
    BrokeredMessage message;
    do
    {
        message = await queue.PeekAsync();
        if (message != null)
        {
            messageList.Add(message);
        }
    } while (message != null);
    return messageList;
}
```