# Few messages failed to send from the messages list using MessageSender.SendAsync(IList<Messages>)

Tags: azureservicebus

I want to understand how will I know if any message or messages failed while sending list of messages to web azure service bus using MessageSender.SendAsync(IList). I understood that messages will move into Dead letter queue after retry but how will get the response back for those.

Also can anyone please let me know where I will get the detailed documentation for this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see that messages are moving to [dead letter queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues) , you can try to read the messages from there and process those.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-dead-letter-queues-to-handle-message-transfer-failures#example
Dead letter queue is a secondary sub-queue where the failed messages are moved to.
The standard paths for DLQ are:

1. {queue path}/$deadletterqueue.
2. {topic path}/Subscriptions//$deadletterqueue

So you need to have another queueClient to read the DLQ for a queue .

Here are more documentations for your reference:
https://dotnetkeyconcepts.com/2018/01/23/dead-letter-queue-dlq-messages-handling-in-azure-topic-subscription/

[How to peek the deadletter messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784331/how-to-peek-the-deadletter-messages)

Comment: Thank you @Jaya.The deadletter messages are confusing me because what I got now is they work with receiving messages functionality and not with the sending. so I do not know what will happen if half of the messages got send successfully and because of some network or any other issue other pending messages couldn't processed. then  will I get anything return in MessageSender.SendAsync(IList) method? :(

Comment: are you talking about sending messages from service bus or sending messages to service bus? well you can check the metrices if that helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor#message-metrics you may set an alert rule for that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric